# Shell Script to find out the PIDs which are not generating any logs for last 24 hours

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I need to write a script for:

1. **select all the PIDs**
2. **check which PIDs are not generating any logs for last 24 hours**
3. **filter those PIDs and kill them**

So please suggest how to write the script

Comment: I need urgent help on this if someone can help that would be really grateful for me.

Comment: No one will write script for you. You should do it and ask if stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give everything away, but only to get you started.

`ps aux | tail -n +2  | awk '{print $2}'`

will give you all the PIDs (step 1).

Good luck